# how to find and block all open gateways for egress calls

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-networking

I have k3s installed and created a testpod in new namespace. I want to know two things:

1. How can I know how many gateways are open for egress calls/outgoing calls when I do `curl -v https://google.com` or  `curl -v https://github.com` from that testpod?
2. Then how can I block(or route traffic from) all these gateways so that the egress traffic goes via common gateway that I will create?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test & check the egress traffic

You can go inside the pod and try the `curl -v https://google.com` or else try `curl ip.me` which return you the Host IP from where request if getting called

In a normal scenario, **Kubernetes** uses the `Worker Node IP` as `Host IP` so you might see **different IPs** if your **POD** is running on different **Node**.

**Manging the single Egress:**

For managing the single **Egress** you can set up the **NAT** **gateway** which will manage all the outgoing traffic from **worker nodes** via a single point.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

If you are on GKE use this : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

For egress gateway support in K3s there is open PR : https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1509

Comment: curl ip.me gives: 43.241.192.218 and  curl -v https://google.com
*   Trying 10.43.223.167:443... .So what will be the gateway of my egress call? gateway means ip address right ?

Comment: Your host or worker node IP is 43.241.192.218. how many worker node are there ? `kubectl get nodes` using something similar to NAT will rsolve your issue to manage the egress

Comment: 1 node is there

Comment: @Harsh--- Is NAT gateway solution you provide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html opensource or is it paid version ?

Comment: it's avilalbe in cloud provider however  https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/deploy-outbound-nat-gateway-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: I already have egress-operator deployed https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#egress-operator . the problem is that the egress traffic is not passing through this operator gateway